# Highlighting pdf using evince?

Tags: evince

I use Evince a lot and I have also tried other alternatives. I just love the smoothness of Evince. Recently, I have the need to highlight text in pdf files. Is it possible to do that in Evince?

Comment: Do you want to highlight text to e.g. copy it to the clipboard, or do you want to modify the PDF file such that the text appears highlighted?

Comment: If you trust the documentation, yes: https://help.gnome.org/users/evince/stable/annotations.html.en I have never tried it though, I use Okular or qpdfview when I need to. Usually they all consider highlighting an annotation, so you might want to search for annotation tools in whichever PDF viewer you use.

Comment: Hi I want to modify text such that text appears highlighted :)

Comment: Yep the annotation works perfectly but i want to highlight text to diff colors

Answer (score 17):

You can use Annotate the document button. Then move to the annotation and click right button, annotation properties, and then select the color.

See http://www.debugpoint.com/2016/05/evince-3-18-2-comes-with-text-and-highlight-annotation-in-ubuntu-16-04/ for visual support (for evince 3.18.2+)

Comment: Thanks i am not being able to right click the annotation, but anyway i found a workaround to bookmark the page so it is quite convenient :)

Comment: For anyone else that comes across this, the annotate button is next to the search button. Click it first, then two more buttons appear. Click the one that says `Add highlight annotation`, your cursor will change and then you can select text to highlight, with an optional note.

Comment: Not so handy in my case (evince 3.10.3) You need to have the sidebar open to access the tab where you have annotations (F9 does). Then, I find no highlight tool and  removing the annotation pads is not as immediate as https://help.gnome.org/users/evince/stable/index.html.en makes believe. If I right-click on a tab, I get the menu of the underlying document, or at least it's hard to get the focus on the tab. Added: highlighting is a feature of evince 3.8.12 but the one I have is the shipping of Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Is there a keyboard shortcut for higlight annotations?

Comment: Note: becko posted the keyboard shortcut question as an 'official' question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/437335/evince-keyboard-shortcut-to-highlight-text) now, although an answer is still missing.

Answer (score 0):

To answer @kiara Grouwstra and @becko question concerning shortcut:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>: highlight text
- <kbd>S</kbd>: add a post-it like note
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>: Add a bookmark

Answer (score 0):

As suggested already, the keybindings `Ctrl` + `H` and `S` can be used to highlight and annotate text. However, this feature is present in evince 3.30+ [[1](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/blob/gnome-3-30/NEWS#L181)] [[2](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/-/merge_requests/54)]. Ubuntu 18.04 ships evince 3.28.

**So to get the keybindings in Ubuntu 18**, I installed the latest version of evince from snap, as suggested by [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1118796/how-do-i-install-evince-3-28-or-newer-on-ubuntu-xenial-16-04-lts) (currently it is 40.4 as opposed to apt's 3.28.4).