# How do I install Evince 3.28 or newer on Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, ppa, evince

Evince 3.28, the default in Ubuntu Bionic 18.04 LTS, introduces several good features, in particular a working fullscreen mode.

Is there a way to install this version - or newer - on 16.04?

The most up to date PPA I was able to find only had 3.24.1, and building from source has proven tricky.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try [Snap'ed version of Evince](https://snapcraft.io/evince):

> ```
> $ snap search evince
> Name    Version  Publisher    Notes  Summary
> evince  3.30.2   ken-vandine  -      Document viewer for popular document formats
> ```

Install it with

```
snap install evince
```

and run with `/snap/bin/evince`.
If you like Snapped version, then remove deb-based with

```
sudo apt purge evince*
sudo apt autoremove
```

For file association open Nautilus, go to folder with PDF file, open context menu on it with right mouse button and select *Open With* and select *Document Viewer* from here.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. I've removed the default evince. Is there a good way to make the snap evince the new default evince?  So that, for example, using `xdg-open some_file.pdf` would launch `/snap/bin/evince`?

Comment: You can use *open with* in nautilus.